# What means attempt_deadline in Google Scheduler if in Google Cloud Run jobs I want a trigger a long job

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

Let's make this case: I set a Google Cloud Run job with a timeout, for example, 4 hours. The job task execution time is 3 hours.

I want to trigger it using Google Cloud Scheduler in a cronjob with a `attempt_deadline` parameter of 120 seconds in a terraform plan.

The job executes fine, but I am worried about the job could be canceled because of `attempt_deadline`.

Is it related to Google Cloud Run jobs and will cancel it while my job is running? If it is, is there an approach to trigger the job?
Or the `attempt_deadline` option is only for the timeout of the request that Google Cloud Scheduler sends to the job to execute it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we tried it, the `attemp_deadline` parameter didn't canceled the job. So it may be not related to the job execution time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.scheduler.v1#job)

> The deadline for job attempts. If the request handler does not respond by this deadline then the request is cancelled and the attempt is marked as a DEADLINE_EXCEEDED failure. The failed attempt can be viewed in execution logs. Cloud Scheduler will retry the job according to the RetryConfig.
>
> One way is to increase the attempt_deadline.The allowed duration for this deadline is:
>
> For HTTP targets, between 15 seconds and 30 minutes. For App Engine HTTP targets, between 15 seconds and 24 hours. For PubSub targets, this field is ignored.

Comment: So, will it stop my job?

Comment: If your job takes longer than the `attempt_deadline`, it will be canceled.

Comment: ok, so if it cancels the job, my second part of the question was, how can I trigger my cloud run job using a cronjob aproach?

Comment: you can set the retry policy to retry the job up to three times in case of failure.Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-retries#console)

Comment: I know, but this is not the case. It won't solve the problem

Comment: can you check this  [document1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule)

Comment: Hi @VíctorM Have you checked the above links

Comment: I wrote more details to the question